# Google Earth Engine Update

Tags: google-earth-engine, error, update

I've opened code editor in google earth engine. in console table this message has shown:

Attention Python and JavaScript client library users!
Earth Engine servers now require client library v0.1.215, released March 11. Please update to the latest Python or JavaScript version to avoid a break in service.

how can I solve this problem?

Sincerely,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are just using the code editor, you can ignore this. If you are developing applications in Python or JavaScript, using the `earthengine-api` package, you should make sure you are using `v0.1.215` or newer.

I can understand it's confusing if you're not doing this type of development. But I'm very happy that they did put it in such a visible location. I had completely missed this, and needed to upgrade.

Comment: Thank you daneil. your answer is really clear and helpful.